# Can i unsubscribe to an event of BasePage from a page which inherits from BasePage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a BasePage having common functionality required by all pages. I have defined a PreRender() event on page base. There are 2-3 pages which does not require this functionality. Can i unsubscribe to PreRender() event of BasePage from my .aspx page. I tried casting BasePage to Page

```
(PageBase as Page).PreRender -= OnPreRender(new EventArgs());
```

but it says PageBase is a type but is used as a variable. How to achieve this. Please suggest.

I am adding PreRender() event as follows:

```
public PageBase()
{
    this.PreInit += new EventHandler(PageBase_PreInit);
    this.PreRender += new EventHandler(PageBase_PreRender);


}
```

Comment: can you not just inherit from `Page` instead of `BasePage`?

Comment: There are other functionalities defined on BasePage which all pages needs. So cannot inherit from page.

Comment: Maybe you need an inheritance tree with three classes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks close. What if you try:

```
base.Page.PreRender -= new EventHandler(Page_PreRender);
```

This assumes you added the event using:

```
base.Page.PreRender += new EventHandler(Page_PreRender);
```

Another option is override the OnPreRender method in your BasePage and use a protected field to check if it should be done. For the three pages, set it to false:

```
    protected bool _useMyCustomPreRender = true;
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_useMyCustomPreRender)
        {
            // do my logic here
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```